# PC game: humorous point-and-click from late 90's about an alien who crash lands on a farm

Tags: story-identification, aliens, video-games

I'm trying to identify a computer game I played once as a kid on someone's computer a long time ago. Here are the relevant memories:

- This was the late 90's or very early 2000's.
- The game was of the point-and-click adventure variety
- The game was on PC. I think it ran on Windows, but I could wrong about this, so DOS games are also a possibility.
- The setting was humorous, the graphics cartoonish.
- The plot resolved around an alien who crash landed on a farm.
- One of the first things to interact was pigs. It could also be that the alien itself looked like a pig, or mind-controlled a pig.
- After that there was a car ride in the dark. I didn't get past that. I think the alien was trying to reach a town to find spare parts for his downed spaceship, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Although the date is wrong, it sounds a bit like this Google Doodle game: https://www.google.com/doodles/roswells-66th-anniversary  But that could easily be referencing an earlier game or just the general "alien crash landing" trope...

Comment: "point and click adventure game alien farm" pulls up a UFO Lets Play.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is the point-and-click game [*U.F.O.s*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.F.O.s_(video_game)) (1997).

It's quite cartoonish and starts with an alien crash-landing on a farm.